# Generate a component as many time as the user want with a click event on ionic

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

Maybe some of you know the Garmin connect app, you can create some training with it. Inside it you can click to "add a repetition" and a little module appears. If you click again it appears again. Here is a example : 
[click](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1icnwmc940o1uk6/RPReplay_Final1588924579.MP4?dl=0)
In ionic this little windows could be a component. How can I generate this component as many time as I want with a click event using ionic ?

Someone as an idea ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an array to save the models and use an *ngFor to iterate through it. With every click you just add a new item to the array

**my-page.html**

```
<!-- ... -->
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of items">
    <my-component [fooValue]="item.foo"><my-component>
</ng-container>

<ion-button (click)="addNewItem()">+</ion-button>
<!-- ... -->
```

**my-page.ts**

```
//...
private items = [];
//...
public addNewItem() {
    const item = {foo: "bar"}; // put every attribute that you will bind to your component
    this.items.push(item);
}
//...
```